# How to transfer my application from one computer to another by making a set up file

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have made a small application using html, php , sql, javascript and jquery. This is kept inside a folder namely `EXAM` in `xampp/htdocs`. An SQL database is used to run the application, with phpMyAdmin for administration.

Now I want to transfer the whole system to another computer.

For this I used to proceed like this:

1. I have to install `phpmyadmin` in that computer
2. Copy and paste my folder EXAM to `xampp/htdocs` of that computer
3. Export my database from computer1 and import it to computer2

How to proceed so that the whole process can be completed by installing one set up file?

Comment: So, you want to know how to make a script that does the "install" for you?

Comment: Exactly. Just provide me the direction

Comment: SO isn't a guide portal, give it a try and come back if you run into problems with the actual code.